# updating a line variable without printing it over an over

Tags: variables, cout

```
for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
    cout<< " I value is: "<< i; 
}
```

how to print "`i value is:`" only once while updating i's value after the first time. 
Thanks your help

Answer (score 1):

Your output has to be outside the scope of the for loop for it to print once otherwise. If you put it within the loop it will print repeatedly until the loop terminates.

> You want something like this :

```
for( int I =0; i<1 10; i++{

perform calculations involving i;

}
cout<< " I value is: "<< i;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cout<< " I value is:";
for(int i=0; i<10;i++) {cout<< " "<< i; }
```

Will this work?

Update:

Assuming you want to add a "thread sleep" in the loop, you can try print "\b" to move the cursor back and override the value, for example:

```
cout<< " I value is: ";
for(int i=0; i<10;i++) {cout<< "\b"<< i; }
```

But depending your computer and compiler, it may not be the result you wanted.

**Final example (tested using Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt):**

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;  
void main()  
{  
    cout<< " I value is:  ";
    for(int i=0; i<10;i++) 
    {
        cout<< "\b"<< i; 
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    } 
}
```

Comment: the question wants updating the line variable without printing it over and over again. Your answer will print the value of i over and over.

Comment: Now I understand what he is asking about, assuming the ideal scenario is that he wants to print value i every sec and loop it 10 times. The output should be only 1 line, but the last digit is changed every 1 sec. For example: first output: "I value is: 0", after 5 sec, the same output line: "I value is: 5", after 9 sec, the same output line: "I value is: 9". See my updated answer for a possible solution.